# New Macbook Pro M1 very slow

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon, monterey, macos

I received a new Macbook Pro 14" M1 with macOS Monterey.
The device is deployed via MDM and is integrated in our AD.

Unfortunately, the device is very slow. Every click e.g. in System Preferences takes up to 1 minute. To open a PDF takes very long. The spinning ball appears and then I need to wait till it is working again.

I've only few apps installed like Word, Excel, Outlook, etc.. So nothing extraordinary.

My old Macbook Pro 2019 Intel is 100 times faster than my new one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does activity monitor tell us about system usage?

Comment: Activity Monitor looks fine, no abnormalities or something else. CPU and Memory are "normal"

Comment: Can you nevertheless add a screenshot of the CPU tab of Activity Monitor, ideally taken while you wait for a PDF or System Preferences to open?

Comment: I suggest you log a support case with the entity which controls the MDM and administers the AD integration. Also, how long has this problem been occurring? How long have you had this laptop?

Comment: I've this device since 3 days and it is occuring from day one. My old device is also with MDM enrolled and AD integrated but even faster.

Comment: Attached two screenshots after a fresh reboot. After opening a PDF File or something else, spinning ball appears again.

Comment: Give it back and demand a new one. If it's an MDM managed device it's most likely not your duty to fix it, have the IT support staff handle this.

Comment: Our Support says that the device is ok and there is no issue. But somethin must be wrong. Maybe to much files on the device? I don't know...

Comment: Please provide a complete screen shot of Activity Monitor while the issue is occurring.